# How can I modify JavaScript to not allow letters in a field?

Tags: javascript, numbers

I am using isNAN at the moment but I can't seem to get it to work.

`if (isNAN(getElementById("Bob")))`

Answer (score 1):

You can use something along the lines of this function to basically check if inp has letters in it.

```
function checkLetter(inp)  
{  
   var letters = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;  
   if(inp.value.match(letters)){  
      //Letters 
   }  
   else {  
      //no letter
   }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (isNaN(document.getElementById("Bob").value))
```

You are not using proper syntax in your code to get value. Also make sure you are using `isNaN()` and not `isNAN()`.

If you want to check `empty` values also:

```
var myVar = document.getElementById("Bob").value;
if(!myVar || isNaN(myVar))
    alert("Not a number!");
else
    alert("Is a number!");
```

Comment: Pls verify the answer for empty value.

Answer (score 0):

you have to check the value, not the object

```
if (isNAN(getElementById("Bob").val()) ){
 //
}
```

EDIT so if you just want lock the field contains numeric values you can do this in html5 :

```
<input type="number" />
```

Comment: `isNaN` should be in proper format. Please update it.

Comment: `.val()` won't work with plain JS - you're mixing this up with jQuery (or another library/framework).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to check if only number exists not letters

```
function isNumber(n) {
  return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}
```

So the use will be like

```
nn=document.getElementById("Bob").value;

ans=isNumber(nn);

if(ans)
{
    //only numbers
}
```

This ans was found from here

[Validate numbers in JavaScript - IsNumeric()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082/validate-numbers-in-javascript-isnumeric)